# (Hyper)Graph canonical labeling - Optimizing for subgraphs [Nauty/Traces?]

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, hypergraph

To a hypergraph, we can apply the following transformations:

- [Vertex Removal of Type A] Remove a specified vertex from the hypergraph. As for the edges that contained this vertex, *remove all of these edges completely*.
- [Vertex Removal of Type B] Remove a specified vertex from the hypergraph. As for the edges that contained this vertex, *just remove the specified vertex from these edges*.

(So in type B vertex removal, an edge only gets completely removed if it contained only the specified vertex and no other vertices.)

The background problem I'm working on is the following:

I start with a hypergraph $H$. Now a series of transformations A,B,A,B,... is applied until there are no more vertices. I need to search through the tree of all choices of vertices for those transformations.

So, for example, if $H$ has 3 vertices {1,2,3}, then the tree looks like the following, where each node represents a hypergraph:

[image: Example of a search tree.]

During the search I look for some things which don't matter for this post.

Now, an important observation to actually do this in practice is that we will often see the same hypergraphs (up to isomorphism). So we can prune the search space by a lot by maintaining a database (hashtable) of hypergraphs we have seen so far (and their characteristics that we are looking for). However, as the hypergraphs will be just isomorphic but have different vertex/edge labels, we need to compute a *canonical representation* of the hypergraph at each stage, and store/search those canonical representations in our database.

For finding canonical hypergraph representations, I use the software Traces.
I convert the hypergraph to a 2-colored graph, with some vertices representing hypergraph vertices and the other vertices representing hypergraph edges. Then Traces can compute a canonical representation of this 2-colored graph.

So far so good, but it is still too slow. To further improve the runtime, we make the following observation: To find a canonical representation, Traces will compute the automorphism group. When passing down our search tree, we will basically look at (some sort of) subgraph of the previous graph, with only one vertex removed. So:

*In the Nauty/Traces/Bliss/saucy/conauto/... algorithm, can one speed up the computation of a canonical label and/or automorphism group of a subgraph with one vertex removed from a supergraph, by knowing the canonical label and automorphism group of the supergraph?*

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but often when people say something is "too slow", it is useful to start by turning the qualitative into quantitative: *how* slow is it currently, and *where* is the time spent? In what language is your program written (C? Interpreted Python?) Have you positively identified where the program is slow? Surprisingly often the reason is not where one might first guess. -- Since your question is ultimately about speed (and algorithms, and implementation), it would be helpful to include some such details in the question.

Comment: Checking the things that I'm looking for in the search tree is negligible. It's a fast check that will sometimes lead to stopping early in a branch (i.e. not considering some branch). You can think of the thing I'm doing as literally just traversing (some subtree of) the search tree mentioned above. So the only things that can be slow are (1) the search space is too big and (2) the canonical form computation is slow, because these are the only things I'm doing. I need any possible speed-up from both of those, in particular from (2). Lastly, be sure that I implement it very efficiently in C++.

Comment: The answer is "no", nobody knows how to do that efficiently. However that doesn't mean nothing can be done.  Approximately how many vertices and edges do your hypergraphs have in the cases where the speed is most of a problem?

Comment: I know the starting hypergraph pretty much exactly. It has about 50-80 vertices and 2-3 times as many edges. I also know where the edges are located, they are very "regularly/uniformly" distributed across the vertices. From this hypergraph, we search the tree as described in the post, so vertices and edges will only become less, and I guess the ratio #edges / #vertices stays around the same factor of 1-5.

Comment: Are you already using the automorphism group to reduce the branching at each node? If $v$ and $w$ are in the same orbit of the automorphism group then you only need consider $A(v)$ (or $B(v)$) but not both.

Comment: True, good tip! I have to look again carefully into the code to see if I'm doing that already. (I know, weird sentence, but it's a longer story.)

Comment: In your example, you have nodes A(1)B(2)A(3) and A(3)B(2)A(1). Aren't these the same hypergraph?  More generally, is the property you want just a function of what hypergraphs are in the tree or does it depend on the structure of the tree?

Comment: In my example, A(1)B(2)A(3) and A(3)B(2)A(1) are definitely the same hypergraph, because they are both the empty hypergraph. But I guess you mean the case where we have more than 3 vertices, in which case I think I agree that they will still be the same.

Comment: Here is what I'm searching for: The tree is a game tree. Player A can make the A(v) moves and player B the B(v) moves. When the hypergraph has a certain property (fast to check), A wins. When the hypergraph has a certain other property (fast to check), B wins. I want to know who wins with start configuration $H$. So I do a minimax search over the tree. I know that there are a lot of other optimizations and pruning methods, but for now I care about improving the canonical label computation by using the same computation of the parent. (The game is basically Tic-Tac-Toe on a general hypergraph.)

Comment: Actually the game is the [Maker-Breaker game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maker-Breaker_game) on a general hypergraph. (But I know the structure of $H$.)

Comment: Removing a vertex and some edges from a hypergraph can drastically change its nature. For example it can cause the automorphism group to grow from trivial to large or shrink from large to trivial. That's why I think there is no general way to reuse the canonical label of a parent hypergraph.

Comment: Let's consider normal graphs. Call the parent graph $G$. Remove $v$, remove all edges that contain $v$, and call the resulting graph $G'$. We know that any element of the stabilizer of $v$ (in Aut(G)) induces an automorphism of $G'$. So when we know Stab(v), we can provide some automorphisms of G' to Traces. I think this is a functionality of Traces and speeds up the computation. Furthermore, to get Stab(v), I think Traces computes it when computing the can. label of $G$, at least for the vertices in the selected cell. For the other vertices, maybe one can also extract it out of Traces' tree?

Comment: Or how fast can we compute the stabilizers from the generators of Aut(G) provided by Traces? Or maybe there are other canonical label algorithms which naturally compute the stabilizers of the vertices (or something close)? Or other canonical label algorithms where some of the work can be reused when computing the can. label of a subgraph?

Comment: Following on from my last question, I guess it generalises to: the hypergraph depends only on the vertices A has removed and the vertices B has removed, not on the order in which they were removed. I assume you are avoiding canonical labelling when that sufficient condition for isomorphism is met. (Use two bit-vectors.) Another thing you can do is lazy canonical labelling: store a cheap-but-strong invariant for each hypergraph and only canonically label it when you find another hypergraph which is not equivalent by the relation at the start of this message but has the same invariant.

Comment: Providing some of the automorphism group to Traces in advance will make it faster for difficult graphs, but for easy graphs the difference will be negligible. Most of your hypergraphs will be easy by that scale.

Comment: On that note, do you expect nauty or Traces to be faster for my graphs?

Comment: In your problem the aim is to detect most isomorphisms and it doesn't matter if you miss a few. So you can use this method: perform a partition refinement. If it is not discrete (all cells singleton), fix an arbitrary vertex in the first non-trivial cell and refine again (starting with the new partition). Keep doing this until you have a discrete partition. Use that as the "canonical" labelling. Almost always it will be unique and the rare exceptions won't matter. Try the nauty refinement routine as well as the Traces one (they use the same graph structure).

Comment: It is hard to predict whether nauty or Traces will be faster for a particular problem.  Only experiment will tell.

Comment: Another thing: some automorphisms slow things down by increasing the automorphism group in a trivial way. Such as: two vertices in the same edges, or two equal edges. That's a fixable problem, let me know if it seems to be common in your case.